# POSTed image via TinyMCE don't appear in MySQL as BASE64 code doesn't send via POST

Tags: codeigniter, post, tinymce, ckeditor, base64

I use Codeigniter+TinyMCE. When I POSTed text and image from textarea in database appears only text. To resolve the issue I increased POST limit size, max_allowed_packet. But it didn't help. Then I output dump:
$_POST['body'] gets only:

```
<p><img alt="" /></p>,
```

but in TinyMCE source code I see:

```
  <p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0....etc.

echo $this->input->post('body', TRUE);
```

shows:

```
     <p><img alt="" /></p> <div id="mcePasteBin" absolute; top: 0px; left: 0;    background:    red; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden" c>  <div c><img alt="" /></div> </div>
```

PS. I insert images from buffer CTRL+C/CTRL+V
Also I installed CKEditor issue same.
Also tried changed form enctype type. (

also it works perfectly without Codeigniter, in simple php.

Comment: $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '+=\a-z 0-9~%.:_-';

Comment: It may be the XSS filter removing the src attributes because they aren't typical URLs.

Comment: You're using Firefox that inserts images that way. In CKEditor you can use this plugin to upload the image to the server and get a normal URL: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/ImagePaste-plugin-for-Firefox

Comment: It seems that some configuration in config.php cause the issue. I tried do it on new installed CI and POST works. After I copied config.php from my project and issue appeared. 
About XSS, I tried use TRUE\FALSE in POST, without success. But I'll try to disable it in config.php....

Answer (score 0):

often data URI images are unrecognized in my experience; my hypothesis is that this is due to their strings either not beginning with "http" or not ending in a known image filetype (.jpg; .png; .tiff; .bmp; etc.)

i am sure there will be solutions for this from within the program(s) you are running, but thought you would be interested in a workaround from without:

shorten the URI to a normal looking string, that ends in the necessary filetype.

if the URI is short enough (under something like three thousand) you can use tinyurl and then pass the result to doiop.com, as they will let you alias to what you wish (including any <*.filetype>) as long as it starts with their domain.  this works for me when posting data base64 encoded files to Blogspot, in those instances where they are rejected.

how you would automate this is another matter; i would be interested.

alternately, you may be able to do this locally on your machine, or by creating an HTML page and using meta-refresh; i will try this and post the results if i am not too busy.

hope that helps.

Comment: So disabling XSS-filtering in config.php resolve my issue. 

Thank you all